# Python - NameError: name 'input' is not defined

Tags: python, input, nameerror

I am trying to construct a program on Python. This is a piece of the program where the problem is. When I run it in Python it runs through the line 'task_name = input("What is the task") but when I put it through Python visualizer it gave me this error: NameError: name 'input' is not defined. This piece of program below is just the start of my program, after it has run this piece I need it to run through the rest of my program but instead it stops and repeats just this piece. Im sorry if I haven't explained this very well, just ask if you don't understand. Please answer, I need to finish this program by tomorrow!
I have used python visualizer http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display and I am using Python 3.2.1.1

```
newTask = "y"
while newTask == "y":
    try:
        numStudents = int(input("How many students are there?"))
    except ValueError:
             print("An integer please")
             continue
    else:
             if numStudents <=1:
                  print("You must enter more than 1 student.")
    task_name = input("What is the task?")
while numStudents == 0:
  for i in range (1,numStudents):
    cont = "y"
    while cont == "y":
        import random
        vol_num = random.randint (1,numStudents)
        print(vol_num) #remove, needs to be hidden
        break

        print("The task is", task_name, ".", "If your number matches the secret number you must complete this task. Good luck!!")
        print("There are", numStudents-student_num, "numbers left which means you have 1 chance in", numStudents, "of being the volunteer!")

        student_name = input("What is your name? Please enter your first name in letters with a maximum of 15.")
        while student_name.isalpha() != True or len(task_name) > 15:
            print("Your first name must be entered in letters with a maximum of 15 letters.")
            student_name = input("What is your name?")

        student_num == 0
        while student_num == 0:
            try:
                student_num = int(input("What is your number? Please enter it as an integer."))
            except ValueError:
                print("You number must be entered as an integer.")
                continue
            else:
                if student_num < 1 or student_num > numStudents:
                    print("That is not a valid number. Please enter the number you were given.")
                    student_num = int(input("What is your number?"))

        if student_num == vol_num:
                print("You are the volunteer! Please complete the task of", task_name, ".")
        else:
                    print("You were lucky this time! You do not have to complete the task!")

        cont = input("Are you the next student? y/n")
        while cont == "n":
            newTask = input("Would you like to enter a new task? (y/n")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks you are getting. There is no "*line in bold*". What "Python visualizer" are you using? What *version* of Python are you using? What happens when you run **just** this code?

Comment: You never change the value of `newTask` so it would be an infinite while loop.

Comment: I cannot replicate your error - please be clearer on the error you're getting.

Comment: HINT: If you get an error when submitting a question because another question already has that title, try making the title more descriptive instead of just putting *PLEASE HELP:)*. That's annoying, and makes people downvote your posts.

Comment: I put your code in a visualizer on the web and I got that error because input wasn't supported.

Comment: @anon To you the visualizer, you would have to used static values and not ask for user input.  i.e. numStudents = 10 **instead of** numStudents = int(input("How many students are there?")) otherwise I would just use your terminal to run the program, by typing the command _python_

Comment: @anon Check out the answer I just submitted.  I'm editing it to give you the ability to have multiple tasks now.

Comment: Please stop vandalising your own post...

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because [Python Visualiser](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) doesn't have a mechanism to allow the user to input data.

You'll need to [Download and install Python](https://www.python.org/) in order to use it interactively as you would like to.

**Additional**

The first while:

```
while newTask == "y":
```

is producing an infinite loop, because it does not set `newTask` anywhere within the loop. `task_name` may be where you intended to use `newTask`.

Alternatively I'm not sure the loop right for what it looks like the purpose of the loop is - the code below may be more appropriate:

```
numStudents = 0
while numStudents < 2:
    try:
        numStudents = int(input("How many students are there?"))
    except ValueError:
             print("An integer please")
             continue
    else:
             if numStudents <=1:
                  print("You must enter more than 1 student.")
# The line below doesn't make much sense in this code block so I've commented it out
#    task_name = input("What is the task?")
```

Another alternative is that you have failed to indent the large portion of the code after your `task_name = input("What is the task?")` line which is causing the infinite loop rather than looping over and over your code. In this case you will need to incorporate the loop above into your `while newTask == "y":`
 loop.

Comment: It might not be so clear because I have only given a part of the program, would it be clearer if I entered the whole program so you could see it and tell me the best option? Thanks

Comment: If @Matthew or my answer doesn't help I would suggest that including more detail may help

Comment: @anon Also, please **don't** post more than a short code snippet in comments, and if you do please use markdown [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) such as backticks for code.

Comment: @MattDMo Im sorry if you don't like the way Ive asked this question or anything but Im not demanding you answer, I have a problem and I really need help with it, Im relatively new to Python so im not nearly as good as most people out there, if you don't want to answer my problem you don't have to, I have posted it so that if someone wants to help me they can

Comment: @anon I understand that, and I apologize for sounding a little harsh. What I was getting at is that this site has rules and expectations, unlike a lot of forums (This is **not** a forum!). You can take the [tour] and read through the [help] to learn more - I strongly recommend it. Basically, questions should be about a single, concise subject - a discrete piece of code you're having problems with, not an entire program that needs to be debugged or optimized. Newcomers are certainly welcome here, as we were all newbies once, but they are expected to understand and comply with the expectations.

Comment: If you have questions at all, read through the [help], browse through old questions, check out [meta], or just ask. We're here to *help*, not chase people away.

Comment: @MattDMo Thankyou, Im just stressing a bit as I have to have my program done tomorrow and I just can't figure out what's gone wrong. I don't want my whole program debugged, I just want to know how to fix my problem and I thought that by showing my whole program it would make my problem clearer. Im going to have other problems because I'm not finished but I can fix those when I come to them. The problem I have is that the first part of my program is repeating and not continuing down to the rest of my program.

Comment: I was finding it hard to make it clear and don't understand lots of the technical terms given in some of the answers so I thought it would be clearer to insert my whole program. I would really appreciate if you could give me your advice on this problem.

Comment: @anon see my answer for some help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The while loop currently will run forever because the case is always true, *newTask == "y"*.  In order to exit the loop newTask needs to be set to something other than "y" causing the case to become false, newTask = "n".

On the other hand it appears that your program doesn't need to be within a newTask while loop at all, because you are storing data a single number and string.  So you could rewrite your program like this:

```
    numStudents = 0 

    while numStudents <= 1:
        try:
            numStudents = int(input("How many students are there?"))
        except ValueError:
            print("An integer please")
        else:
            if numStudents <= 1:
                print("You must enter more than 1 student.")

    task_name = input("What is the task?")
```

Comment: Thanks so much! What I am trying to do is create a program which lets someone enter a task and then hand out numbers to students (not set by computer). then the students will take turns in entering their numbers until the volunteer is found. (The volunteer number is randomly selected by the computer) Would it be easier if I entered the whole program so you could see it and give me the best option of what to do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to rewrite your whole program, but I'll give you a few pointers that should help out.

On a side note, why did you try to vandalize your post? Once answers have been posted, it cannot be deleted (except in certain circumstances by members of the community, and even then it's still visible to high-rep users). Everything posted here is licensed under [CC-BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), as listed at the bottom of every page. Basically, as soon as you post something, it's the same as editing a Wikipedia article - it's there forever, even if someone edits it. Basically, getting it deleted *entirely* requires the internet equivalent of an act of a god (the Stack Exchange sys admins).

At any rate, if you haven't already, [download Python 3.4.3](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-343/) (the current version of Python 3) and install it on your computer. If for some reason you can't do that (public/shared workstation, etc.), then use a free cloud site like [PythonAnywhere](http://pythonanywhere.com) - all an account requires is an email address. If you're working on your own computer, I'd also *highly* recommend installing a programming editor like [Sublime Text 3](http://sublimetext.com/3). It includes lots of cool features like syntax highlighting, automatic bracket matching, etc.*****

<sup>*****If you want to trick it out a bit, install [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation), then install the following plugins: [Anaconda](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda), [Python Improved](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Improved), and the [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme). I wrote the last 2 to aid in Python programming. They're not required, but are very helpful for me. YMMV. Just a note - maybe save all this stuff until *after* your assignment is done. It's very easy to get distracted with shiny new stuff :)</sup>

OK, on to the program itself. Load it up in Sublime or PythonAnywhere, both of which have line numbers (a very important feature if you're programming). I'll be using the line numbers of the program as [currently shown](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31767933/8) in your question.

First thing: watch your indentation. Sublime has a great feature where you can have vertical lines showing where your indented blocks should be (if you install `Neon`, they're dark gray and unobtrusive, while still visible). They should be turned on by default. Remember that indentation is extremely important in Python, and variable indentation can cause errors. Each indented block should be 4 spaces deep, no more and no less, and it is *very highly recommended* that you not use tabs. Lines 6, 7, 9, and 10 are over-indented (9 spaces for 6, 7, and 9 instead of 4, and 5 spaces for 10 instead of 4 as compared to the line above it). In Sublime, you can highlight some text, then change its indentation using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> to move it left, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to move it right (use <kbd>⌘</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on OS X). There are more indentation issues in the second `while` loop as well.

Line 2 starts a `while` loop that goes until Line 11. The thing to remember about `while` loops is, you **have to** have some way of changing the loop's test condition **within the loop itself**. The test condition here is `newTask == "y"`. Unless `newTask` is changed to some value other than `"y"` inside the loop, it will continue forever. A `break` statement or an unhandled `Error` or `Exception` will also kill a `while` loop. Since `newTask` is only changed at the very bottom of the *next* `while` loop, you may want to indent that entire second loop so that it is contained within the first one. I don't know what the ultimate purpose of your program is, so you'll have to figure that one out on your own.

The second `while` loop starts with the following:

```
while numStudents == 0:
  for i in range (1,numStudents):
```

Assuming you fix the issues with the first loop, this will do nothing, and may lock up your program. Start up Python on the command line (or open a new Python 3.4 console in PythonAnywhere) and run the following:

```
list(range(1, 0))
```

You'll get

```
[]
```

as the output. The [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) function's signature is

```
range(stop)
range(start, stop[, step])
```

meaning that if 1 argument is passed, `range()` produces a sequence from 0 to the integer **before** `stop` (it's very important to remember that). If 2 arguments are passed, the sequence goes from the 1st (`start`) to the number before the 2nd (`stop`), in increments of 1 or `step` if it is present. `stop` can be smaller than `start`, producing a decreasing series of numbers instead of increasing, **if** `step` is also a negative number:

```
>>> list(range(10, 1))
[]
>>> list(range(10, 1, -1))
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Your call to `range()` produces nothing, so nothing below Line 13 will run. It will just loop back to Line 12, which will still evaluate to `True` because `numStudents` hasn't been changed, so this loop will run forever as well.

Hopefully this will give you enough to get started. Think about each block of code, and the condition(s) you set for executing it. Make sure that the conditions being tested get altered at some point, otherwise you'll end up with either infinite loops, or code blocks not being executed at all. Make *heavy* use of the interactive console to test code snippets to make sure they do what you think they should do before putting everything together.

Good luck!